Arduino Nano max current from 5v pin if using 5v 1A wall adapter
I read several answers, but those can be confusing, because it depends on how you provide power to the Arduino.
What if I use a wall adapter with 5 V / 1 A and connect it directly to the Arduino Nano USB type-c port? How much current will that 5 V pin support then?
For instance, can I power a 1 A lamp from a 5 V pin and ground pin?
If no, what is a preferable way to do this if I still want to use a USB port?

wouldn't you expect the arduino to use some of the available current?

If you've got the wall adapter plugged into the USB port, then why not take power off of that instead and not have to worry about it.  Tap into the 5V in that wire.

Instead of powering the lamp from the Arduino's 5V pin, use a separate 5V power supply that can provide enough current for the lamp (e.g., a 5V/2A supply).

After working in digital electronic, analog electronics can catch many people off guard. A power supply rated up to 1 amp may not work well close to its rated limit. The voltage may drop unexpectedly.
Also, according to this schematic, on the Arduino Nano, between the USB voltage net (VUSB) and the 5 volt Arduino Nano net (+5V), there is a fuse (MSMF050) that operates in the 0.5Amp range and should trip at about 1.0Amps. Pulling the trip current may trigger this fuse.
Some people design with much wider margins. For example, if a device or part requires 1A to operate some people use a power supply who's limit is double or 2A.
Note, there is the fuse in the Arduino Nano that should trip at about 1.0A so using a larger power supply would not work here. Consider supplying power to the external device or part directly from a capable power supply.
